# Jira Build Status Gadget gives JSON parse error

Tags: json, jenkins, build, jira

When adding the Build Status gadget to my Jira Dashboard pointing to my Jenkins project I receive the following error:

```
Build status loading error: failed to parse JSON
Response content: Requests to http://myHost:8080/job/myProject/api/json? 
nocache=1537429838 are not allowed. See your administrator about configuring a 
whitelist entry for this destination (http://confluence.atlassian.com/x/KQfCDQ).
```

Is there anything on the Jenkins side which needs enabling/configuring?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL for the Jenkins builds must be white listed in Jira